# Stocks: do Good Till Cancelled orders get executed during after hours?

Tags: stocks, financial-literacy, stock-markets, after-hours-trading

If I place a stop loss GTC order on my shares at $80, and it reaches that price during pre-market or after hours, will my order get executed?

I ask because a lot of the time the stock opens at a different price than what it closed at, so if the stock sank from $85 to $50 during after hours, I'm wondering if my GTC order would get executed.

Comment: No it won't get executed after hours, but if your stop is a market order you will be stopped out at the open if it opens at $50 (from $85 the night before) and your stop is above $50.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd have to check the rules for your broker to make sure that the term is being used in its usual sense, but the typical answer to your question is "no."  A GTC will execute during market hours.  You would need to explicitly specify extended hours if you want to execute outside of market hours (which your broker may or may not support).

Comment: This is how it should be. 

For example, with Interactive Brokers' platform you can select GTC as an order type. The extra info given states that it will only be executed during business hours. There is an additional check box in the order window to allow after hour execution.

Answer (score 1):

When I place an order with Scottrade I also have to specify if I am wanting to trade outside of normal hours.

Answer (score 1):

You typically need to specify that you want the GTC order to be working during the Extended hours session. I trade on TD Ameritrade's Thinkorswim platform, and you can select DAY, GTC, EXT or GTC_EXT. So in your case, you would select GTC_EXT.